# Attempting to parse a line, character by character using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have a line that can look different depending on the input. My current method that is not working, is to loop over it using `range()` so I can get the current position.
The line consists of the word "LR" then a "left" string and a "right" string separated by a space. The problem is, you can not split it at all of the spaces because sometimes the left and/or right string has a space in it itself, causing the actual left or right string to be split more than once.
2 example inputs that demonstrate this are:

```
LR "redirect\":\"\\" "\"" ->
```

This one you would not have a problem separating using a space.

```
LR "name=\"uuid\" value=\"" "\""
```

This one fails on regex.

```
LR "<span class=\"pointsNormal\">" "<" ->
```

This one as you can see has a space in the left side of the string after 'span'.

```
    def parseLR(self, line) -> None:
        
        line = line.split("LR ")[1].split(" ->")[0]

        left = ""
        seen = 0
        encountered = False

        for x in range(len(line)):

            char = line[x]

            if encountered and seen % 2 == 0:
                break

            if char == '"' and line[x - 1] != '\\':
                seen += 1

            elif char == " ":
                encountered = True
            
            left += char
        
        print(left)
```

This is my current approach. I go character by character, on each character check, I check if it is a ", if so I increment the seen counter, if it is not, I check if the char is a space, if it is, I set `encountered` to True. Then regardless of that, I check if seen is even meaning there is an equal number of " in the string, and if there has been a space encountered. If so that is the end of the LEFT string. If you run it, you will see the problem that occurs. How can I properly parse the left string and right string from the lines?

Comment: You need to count double quotes, BUT ignore a double quote that was preceded by a backslash.

Comment: @TimRoberts - that actually won't work on the "redirect" example, because there is an escaped backslash before the quote. It is more correct to say that it should be split on spaces that are preceded by a quote that is not escaped, but that becomes far more complicated.

Comment: Yes, a more accurate statement would be "you need to handle backslash escapes".

Comment: @TimRoberts - hah you said the same thing while I was editing mine to say it. I think my replace/split method is the easiest way. It works for all of the cases that were posted...

Comment: @OneMadGypsy is this possible using the standard split method since there are no constraints on it, im assuming you just made your own?

Comment: @Noah my answer will not work, but I am considering the shortest possible way that will. Maybe my answer will change, soon.

Comment: interesting, I will update my question so you can possible build off of it

Comment: @Noah Do you need the backslashes to remain after the split? In other words if your "redirect" example was split into `['"redirect":"', '"""']`, would that be sufficient?

Comment: this should work, if this route is taken, a solution would be to just unescape the string first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254341/discussion-between-onemadgypsy-and-noah).

Comment: I undeleted and changed my answer to the proper one. The way you settled on last night only works for your specific cases. My answer works period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should split any string on a space that is preceded by a double quote that is not escaped. Commented for clarity.

```
file = r'''
LR "name=\"uuid\" value=\"" "\"" ->
LR "redirect\":\"\\" "\"" ->
LR "[{'userLevel': '" "'" ->
LR "<span class=\"pointsNormal\">" "<" ->
'''

def splitdata(line:str) -> tuple:
    for i, c in enumerate(line):
        #create a cache of the last 3 characters, pad if necessary
        cache = line[max(0, i-3):i].rjust(3, " ")
        
        #if this character is not a space preceded by a double quote, skip
        if not (c==' ' and cache[-1]=='"'): continue
        
        #if the quote is not escaped LR has been found
        if cache[-2] != "\\" or cache=='\\\\"': break
    
    #return LR
    return line[:i], line[i+1:]

     
for line in file.split('\n'):
    if line:
        #it's better to do this here 
        #so splitdata doesn't become specific to your file
        line = line.split('LR ')[1].split(' ->')[0]
        left, right = splitdata(line)
```

Comment: You could just split on `'" "'` and get essentially the same result.  And here's a case where this fails:  `LR "left \"side\" " "right side" ->`.  Character-by-character parsing is the only way.

Comment: @TimRoberts - fair-enough. I will make my answer better. Temporary delete.